# Relative virtual address in different library file formats

Tags: assembly, linker

This question is related to all formats of library files (COFF,ELF32/64...)

Can RVA offset be 64bit length? if so, what are the criteria for that to happened / which library format use 64bit offsets? 
Is there a standard of RVA structure with compatible sizes for each field (offset,symbol name..) or each library format has its own structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [ELF64](http://www.uclibc.org/docs/elf-64-gen.pdf) the offsets and the addresses (ELF don't use *RVA*s) are `ELF64_Off` and `ELF64_Addr` which are 64 bit long.

[PE+](http://wiki.osdev.org/PE#64_bit_PE) still use 32 bit offsets and RVAs.

[ELF32](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) use `ELF32_Off` and `ELF32_Addr` which are 32 bit long.

Of course each library use its own format.

*RVA*s are just numbers, they are used where needed in the structures used by the file format.
*RVA*s are a different concept from *Offsets*, which are usually used to index tables (including symbols tables).